# Member function pointers - only a address?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, functor, pointer-to-member

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/fastdelegate2.aspx

In the second paragraf of the introduction in the above article it says: "This is due to the expensive heap memory allocation that is required to store the member function and the bound object on which member function call is made."  .. I dont get this? Does it actualy have to copy and store the object and the member function? Doesn't it only store the address of the member function?

Comment: A non-static member function is associated with a specific object.  Something like `matrix->Invert()` inverts one specific matrix, so it has to know which matrix to operate on.

Answer (score 3):

Boost.Function is more general and powerful than raw function pointers: they can store anything that is callable with a particular signature.  However, there is a cost in storage and run-time associated with that flexibility.

The [Miscellaneous Notes section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function/misc.html) of the Boost.Function documentation talks a bit more about this, but to summarize:

- A Boost.Function object stores a member function pointer and two data pointers internally.
- It may require a heap allocation if storing a functor that is larger than a certain size.
- Calling a Boost.Function object results in either one or two calls through a function pointer, depending on what exactly was stored.

Having said all that, I've used Boost.Function extensively and never had a situation where its storage or run-time costs actually showed up when profiling, so whether any of this is important or not will depend on your actual usage.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can't call a member function with only the pointer to the method. The reason is because methods are called within a **context** (`this`), the object on which the method is called. If you only have the member function pointer you can't know to which object the method should be applied. However, if the member function is `static`, then it does **NOT** have a context, because static member functions can be called without instantiating an object.

So to call a member function you need a pointer to the function, **PLUS** some reference to an object defining the context in which the call to member function will take place.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes kinda, but wouldn't a reference be pretty much a pointer to the object? So thats two pointers? Is that all there is? From the line I quoted it sounds like theres more too it?

Comment: Yes, it is all that is :-). However, while the method is a piece of code that always exists (so the pointer to the method is always valid), there are **object lifespan** issues that complicate the implementation of the pointer to the object. Sometimes, you are obliged to create a copy of the object to ensure that the pointer remains valid. Do you want me to give you a complete example using `boost::function` or you can just look at [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html) from the official docs.

Comment: hmm.. So its thoes sometimes that will be the "expensive heap allocation" they mean in that quote then? Cause alocating memory for two pointers wouldn't be expensive.. I've used std/boost ::function plenty of times so I know how its done..

Comment: `boost::function` will indeed make a heap allocation to store a copy of the context (either a copy of the whole object or a copy of a reference if you use `boost::ref`). Whether this is **expensive** or not is relative. As you say, allocating a few pointers is not a big deal, but it's still an allocation, so if you do it in a loop you will be calling a complicated system call many times...